Material React Table - GlobalFilterTextField triggers infinity render loop
Hej at all,
thanks in advance for your time and effort.
We use a dialog which is controlled by a "material-ui-popup-state". In this dialog a material react table is displayed. Everythings working fine if only the table body is displayed.
If we render the MRT_GloabelFilterTextField the dialog triggers an infinite render loop.
If you manage to type something in the textfield during constant rerender, the loop ends and the correct filtered rows are shown. If you clear the textfield again, the loop starts again.
This problem doesn't occur, if we use an own textfield with states controlled by us. But then we loose the automatic highlighting and several other benefits from the material react table.
Can someone explain this behaviour and ho to fix it?
Thank you very much for your help, effort and time!
